# setOnItemLongClickListener not working after a togglebutton is placed in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-togglebutton

I am trying to implement a Custom adapter for ListView where I have two TextViews and a ToggleButton. Before the togglebutton I was able to use setOnItemLongClickListener which I can not now and I know that focus is on togglebutton so is the issue. However I want two operation work simultaneously so I have tried to use:

```
 android:longClickable="true"
 android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Then I tried to use

```
listView1.setLongClickable(true);
```

Tried to return true in **onItemLongClick**

However, these things are not working. How can I handle this?

Comment: For which layout u gave this android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

Comment: I have given this attribute to ListView which is in FrameLayout!!!!

Comment: give this attribute to adapter layout

Comment: Use TouchListener for the toggle button, and return false from it. I guess doing this should make the longClickListener work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this Attribute to **Adapter** Layout

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Comment: What is "Adapter layout"?